# How to Populate Title Field in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Newby coder here so excuse the ignorance:

Table 1 (title table) list different titles like mr, mrs, dr, prof, etc (column name = 'title_name') and the primary key is named 'id' which is marked from 1 to 4 (linking that to the title obviously)

Table 2 (member table) has a column named 'title' that show 1,2,3,4, etc as the title of the member

How do I write a sql statement that will populate the actual title and not the id?

I tried the following: 
select title
from member, title
where member.title=title.title_name

I get the following error however:
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Dr' to data type int

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join on the correct column:

```
select title_name from member, title where member.title=title.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can link data by using a JOIN operation.
For example with the query I'm giving here you get all the members with the related record from title:

```
   select * from member as m left join title t on t.id = m.title;
```

If you need specific fields from the query you can just replace "*" with the names of the fields.

Answer (score 0):

Try;

```
select
    t.title_name
from title t
join member m on m.title = t.id
```

Comment: While this answer may be correct, please add some explanation. Imparting the underlying logic is more important than just giving the code, because it helps the OP and other readers fix this and similar issues themselves.